# Update SQL with checkbox values

Tags: sql, checkbox, coldfusion

I can display checkbox states from a SQL query, but I can't update them. I'm using bit as the data type. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the way I'm using cfif to test the values of the checkboxes. If I comment them out, any values I have in the table get overwritten by the cfparam defaults, and I get my little confirmation message on the action page.  I've tried cfif, cfif isDefined, etc. I've been reading and working on this since last week, just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Here's the sample code from my test server: (fyi I'm using the same action page to view and update the record.)

```
<cfif isDefined ("form.update")>

<cfparam name="checkbox1" default=0>
<cfparam name="checkbox2" default=0>
<cfparam name="checkbox3" default=0>
<cfparam name="checkbox4" default=0>


<cfif #form.chkbox1# EQ checked>
<cfset checkbox1=1>
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined (form.chkbox2)>
<cfset checkbox2=1>
</cfif>

<!--- <cfif IsDefined (form.chkbox3)>
<cfset checkbox3=1>
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined (form.chkbox4)>
<cfset checkbox4=1>
</cfif> --->

<cfquery name="update" datasource="HHSCIntra">

    UPDATE tbl_checkbox
    SET chkbox1 = #checkbox1#, chkbox2=#checkbox2#, chkbox3=#checkbox3#, chkbox4=#checkbox4#
    WHERE RecID = #user#

</cfquery>

<cfoutput>Record number: #user# Updated.</cfoutput>

<cfelse>

<cfquery name="checkboxview" datasource="HHSCIntra">

    SELECT * FROM tbl_checkbox WHERE RecID = #form.nameselect#

</cfquery>

<cfif #checkboxview.chkbox1# EQ 1>
<cfset chkbox1checked="yes">
<cfelse>
<cfset chkbox1checked="no">
</cfif>

<cfif #checkboxview.chkbox2# EQ 1>
<cfset chkbox2checked="yes">
<cfelse>
<cfset chkbox2checked="no">
</cfif>

<cfif #checkboxview.chkbox3# EQ 1>
<cfset chkbox3checked="yes">
<cfelse>
<cfset chkbox3checked="no">
</cfif>

<cfif #checkboxview.chkbox4# EQ 1>
<cfset chkbox4checked="yes">
<cfelse>
<cfset chkbox4checked="no">
</cfif>

<cfform action="checkboxaction.cfm" method="post">

<cfoutput query="checkboxview">#name#</cfoutput>

<cfinput name="user" type="hidden" value="#checkboxview.RecID#"><br>


        Checkbox 1: <cfinput type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" checked="#chkbox1checked#" value=1><br>
        Checkbox 2: <cfinput type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" checked="#chkbox2checked#" value=1><br>
        Checkbox 3: <cfinput type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" checked="#chkbox3checked#" value=1><br>
        Checkbox 4: <cfinput type="checkbox" name="chkbox4" checked="#chkbox4checked#" value=1><br>

<br>

<cfinput type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

</cfform>

</cfif>
```

Mahalo

Comment: The check box should be coming back as "on" from your form. Whatever value you have set to the variable checked must not be "on". Also ditch the cfinput and cfform and use regular form and input tags.

Comment: It is because you are using different names for your `cfparam` statements and the checkbox fields. So you are not assigning defaults - you are actually creating totally new variables. The names must match.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of places you could clean up/improve the code. You may want to post it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to use cfparam, as in:

```
<cfparam name="form.chkbox1" default="0" overwrite="false" />
```

And then use the value of the variable in your cfquery:

```
SET chkbox1 = <cfqueryparam value="#form.chkbox1#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" />
```

Your view is setting the value to 1 if checked. If it isn't checked, it won't be passed in the form scope.

Comment: (Edit) Agreed on scoping variables.  (Though the reason are getting the default value every time is because the names of the input fields do not match the names used in the cfparam statements, ie `chkbox1` versus `checkbox1`. )  +1 for scoping and cfqueryparam.

Comment: Thanks, trying to get Steve's answer to work, but cold fusion is throwing all kinds of errors on the cfparam tag. Attribute validation error for tag CFPARAM.  
It does not allow the attribute(s) VALUE. The valid attribute(s) are DEFAULT,MAX,MIN,NAME,PATTERN,TYPE.  The test server is ColdFusion 9, are those attributes not supported in 9? Also threw the error on the cfsqltype attribute. It's throwing the error on View, not sure why it's doing that since all that code is nested in the cfif isDefined form.update tag. Shouldn't all that code be skipped when I just click on View? Mahalo.

Comment: This works: <!--- <cfparam name="form.chkbox1" default="0">
<cfparam name="form.chkbox2" default="0">
<cfparam name="form.chkbox3" default="0">
<cfparam name="form.chkbox4" default="0">

<cfquery name="update" datasource="HHSCIntra">

 UPDATE tbl_checkbox
 SET chkbox1 = #form.chkbox1#, chkbox2=#form.chkbox2#, chkbox3=#form.chkbox3#, chkbox4=#form.chkbox4#
 WHERE RecID = #user#

</cfquery> ---> Was I misunderstanding something in Steve's answer?

Comment: I guess in part, I answered my question about the code within the cfif tags. Obviously ColdFusion checks the code on a page when it opens, regardless of whether it's being executed or not. I do have an additional question. The production application for this is using cfinserts and cfupdates rather than cfqueries. These checkboxes are just an addition to the existing application. Should I try to incorporate the checkboxes within the existing cfupdate and cfinserts, or handle them separately in a cfquery? Mahalo

Comment: Take a look at Steve's example again. It does not use "value" for the `cfparam` statement.  You are probably confusing `cfparam` and `cfqueryparam`. The two are totally different.  [`cfqueryparam`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam) is used to protect your database query against sql injection.  It seems like you may be new to CF. If so, I would recommend reading [the documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ColdFusion+Tags) first. There are also some good intro sites, as well, like http://www.learncf.com/.

Comment: Yeah, a real noob when it comes to this stuff. I've used learncf.com a lot, good site. Been to a few others as well, Nadal's site, easycfm, etc. lot's to learn. I was able to get this working, Steve's answer got me going in the right direction, much appreciated. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Comment: Yep, always a lot to learn with a new language.  While some things will be a matter of stylistic preference - using cfqueryparam is not :) Your original query puts your db at risk for [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So best to get into the habit of using cfqueryparam now. (BTW, you mentioned `cfupdate/cfinsert`. Those are legacy tags that are not used much anymore in new code, but ... the topic of streamlining code is really better conversation for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ;-)

Comment: Agree with you on cfqueryparam, we get a little lax on that because there's no public connection to this server, it's strictly internal use only, but that's no excuse to skirt best practices. I replaced the cfupdate with cfquery and that works, I'm trying to do the same with cfinsert for new records, but I'm having some backend SQL issues with the insert query. Troubleshooting is complicated by the fact that the test server is not processing cfm tags from the server browser, trying to figure that one out now, don't know if it's a coldfusion or IIS issue.